# How to set default language for ios app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, localization

My app contains 4 different languages. Developing language was English now I want to set some other language(Russian) as default language(App language have to be Russian when app installs the first time) how can I achieve this?

In my app delegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {  
     NSBundle.setLanguage(defaultLanguage)  
}   

extension NSBundle {
    class func setLanguage(language: String) {
        defer {
            object_setClass(NSBundle.mainBundle(), Language.self)
        }

        objc_setAssociatedObject(NSBundle.mainBundle(), &bundleKey, NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(language, ofType: "lproj"), .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)

    }
}
```

I have added this code but the language is not changing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a UserDefaults to store current language. If not set, use the default language.

This is Chinese for example:

```
var bundle: Bundle? = nil

func setLanguage(_ index: Int) {
    switch index {
    case 0:    
        print("Set language to En.")
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Base", ofType: "lproj")
        self.bundle = Bundle.init(path: path!)
    case 1:     
        print("Set language to Zh.")
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "zh-Hant", ofType: "lproj")
        self.bundle = Bundle.init(path: path!)
    case 2:     
        print("Set language to Ch.")
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "zh-Hans", ofType: "lproj")
        self.bundle = Bundle.init(path: path!)
    default:
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "zh-Hant", ofType: "lproj")
        self.bundle = Bundle.init(path: path!)
        break
    }

}

func get(_ key: String) -> String {
    if self.bundle != nil {
        return NSLocalizedString(key, tableName: "Localizable", bundle: bundle!, value: "", comment: "")
    }
    return ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may save your current language in `NSUserDefaults`. Create different text files to save different language specific data as key-value pair for read & write. Each file can contain only that key-value of that language. e.g. for key-string `home,` `english.txt` contain value `home` where `bangla.txt` contain `নীড়` etc.

Then you create a class for `UniversalLanguageProvider` for getter and setter method. Just create a dictionary and save all the text data from text file to this according to the language you set in `NSUserDefaults`.

For first time app launching, current language will be `nil`. Then you can set explicitly as **russian** like this:

```
NSString* language = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"language"];
if(!language)
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"russian" 
forKey:@"language"];
```

Comment: i have tried this method but its not updating in first launch . In second launch its work perfectly